# Double fadeIn using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, fadein

I'm trying to use .fadeIn() to make my dynamic content swap look a little more smooth. Except I'm getting what I can only describe as a double fade (in and out and back in again).

I'm brand new to JS and the jQuery API so any help appreciated.

Demo page: http://robert-richter.com/boilerplate/

```
$('nav a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault() 
        var href = "inc/" + this.href.split('=').pop() + ".php"
        $('.con').hide().load(href).fadeIn; 
        if (href == 'inc/blog.php') {
            document.title = 'Robert-Richter.com | Blog';
            window.location.hash = 'index.php?content=blog';
        } else if (href == 'inc/portfolio.php') {
            document.title = 'Robert-Richter.com | Portfolio';
            window.location.hash = 'index.php?content=portfolio';
        } else if (href == 'inc/lebenslauf.php') {
            document.title = 'Robert-Richter.com | Lebenslauf';
            window.location.hash = 'index.php?content=lebenslauf';
        } else if (href == 'inc/kontakt.php') {
            document.title = 'Robert-Richter.com | Kontakt';
            window.location.hash = 'index.php?content=kontakt';
        } else {
            document.title = 'Robert-Richter.com';
            window.location.hash = '';
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Also the window.location.hash-thing adds a # between like `domain/boilerplate/#index.php?content=blog`

Comment: You shouldn't have any fadein because you don't executing a function only access the function. it should be `$('.con').hide().load(href).fadeIn();`

Comment: For your second question, that is the expected behavior. The `#` is called a "hash", so `window.location.hash` defines the string that follows the hash in the URL.

Comment: SO has all the answers. Balint Bako's solution should work.

Comment: Yes it works just fine. Thank you Balint Bako! Still looking for a solution for the URL.

Comment: Just a comment: I would have a look at `switch` instead of so many `if else` statements.

Comment: To be honest I never used switch in JS. :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one, it won't show again until the new page is loaded:

```
$('.con').hide().load(href, function () {
    $('.con').fadein();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a hash you need to use [History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html), there are libraries that use it or hash change if not supported by the browser like [hash.js](https://github.com/blasten/hash.js) or [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/).

Comment: Hm this documentation says its not supported my IE and Android. Is there a different way?

Comment: History API is the only way to change url without a hash.

Comment: What do you think about https://github.com/browserstate/history.js and http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/navigation/